# passing model in checkbox?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Model:

```
[DisplayName("waiting for activation")]
public string  Awaiting { get; set; }
```

aspx:

```
<div class="field forCheckbox">                             
    <%:Html.CheckBoxFor(model=>model.Awaiting)%>                         
    <%:Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Awaiting) %>                   
    <%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.Awaiting) %>
</div>
```

note: Its is a checkbox group. except this checkbox value all others are bool.

error: `cannot convert convert bool to string`?

how do i do?

Comment: post your full model class, it may help

Answer (score 0):

Make your property a `bool`

```
public bool Awaiting { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public bool Awaiting { get; set; }
```

Instead

Comment: i am passing a string value. so i want that to be string.

Comment: If you need to use Awaiting later on in your code just use Awaiting.ToString() to convert it back into a string where needed